# Async Task Creates Memory Leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, .net-8.0

Here I have a Method `ImportFbxAsync();` , That first calls `BuildMaterialBankAsync();`  and keep it running asynchronously without `await`   because it takes time  then `BuildScene()` in another task then i wait for the result of `BuildMaterialBankAsync() ;`  and then i continue my work ;
The problem is that `BuildMaterialBankAsync();`   Will create a Memory Leak that never gets released even if the method were to return/stop early when  `if (fbxPath == null)`   or   `if (ShowImportOptions(importOptions))`   and the leak will continue for the lifetime of the app

```
public class FbxImport
{
    public static async Task ImportFbxAsync(StudioViewModel studioView)
    {
        studioView.IsBackgroundLoading = true;

        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new();

        // Build material bank asynchronously
        var materialBankTask = BuildMaterialBankAsync(studioView, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        var fbxPath = GetFbxFilePath(studioView);

        if (fbxPath == null)
        {
            Logger.Log(0, "Import canceled.", "Import canceled");
            studioView.IsBackgroundLoading = false;
            // Cancel the materialBankTask
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

            return;
        }

        Logger.Log(17, fbxPath, "Importing...");

        // No Memory Leak Detected From  BuildScene ATM !
        var fBXScene = await BuildScene(studioView, fbxPath);

        // Wait For material bank From BuildMaterialBankAsync Task
        var materialBankResult = await materialBankTask;

        try
        {
            if (fBXScene == null)
            {
                Logger.Log(18, "Fbx Import Failed ", "Fbx Import Failed ", false);
                return;
            }
            var importOptions = CreateImportOptions(
                studioView.TargetedGame,
                fBXScene,
                materialBankResult
            );

            //Possible to Cancel Here
            if (ShowImportOptions(importOptions))
            {
                await ProcessBones(studioView, importOptions, fBXScene);
                await ProcessMeshes(studioView, importOptions, fBXScene);
                await ProcessDummies(studioView, importOptions, fBXScene);

                Logger.Log(19, $"{fbxPath} \n imported successfully", " Successful Import.");
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Log(0, "Import canceled.", "Import Canceled");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(0, ex.ToString(), "Import Faild", false);
        }
        finally
        {
            fBXScene?.Dispose();
            materialBankResult?.Dispose();
            materialBankTask?.Dispose();
            studioView.IsBackgroundLoading = false;
        }
    }

    public static async Task<MaterialInfoBank> BuildMaterialBankAsync(
        StudioViewModel studioView,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken
    )
    {
        var filePath = $"IncludeResources\\MaterialBanks\\Bank{studioView.TargetedGame}.xml";

        return await Task.Run(
            () => MaterialInfoBank.ReadFromXML(filePath),
            cancellationToken
        );
    }
}
```

[Rider Memory Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP9N4.png)

[Rider Memory Profile Before Calling ImportFbxAsync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teWww.png)

[Rider Memory Profile After Calling ImportFbxAsync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmUmY.png)

Is there a way to fix this? or a guid to understand how to ?

also ,I don't own The `MaterialInfoBank`   Object Class and I dont know how it works but i know that it reads a xml file and parse it to three  Dictionaries

```
   public Dictionary<string, MaterialDef> MaterialDefs = new Dictionary<string, MaterialDef>();
   public Dictionary<string, XmlStructDef> GXItemStructs = new Dictionary<string, XmlStructDef>();
   public Dictionary<string, List<byte[]>> DefaultGXItemDataExamples = new Dictionary<string, List<byte[]>>();
```

so i tried to add disposal pattern <as far as i understand `IDisposable`> to it but it didn't work the leak still continues

```
   protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
       if (!disposedValue)
       {
           if (disposing)
           {
               // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects)
               MaterialDefs.Clear();
               GXItemStructs.Clear();
               DefaultGXItemDataExamples.Clear();
               MaterialDefs = null;
               GXItemStructs = null;
               DefaultGXItemDataExamples = null;
           }

           // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override finalizer
           // TODO: set large fields to null
           disposedValue = true;
       }
   }

   // // TODO: override finalizer only if 'Dispose(bool disposing)' has code to free unmanaged resources
   // ~FLVER2MaterialInfoBank()
   // {
   //     // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
   //     Dispose(disposing: false);
   // }

   public void Dispose()
   {
       // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
       Dispose(disposing: true);
       GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
   }
```

Comment: Is my guess that `MaterialInfoBank.ReadFromXML` is not async correct?

Comment: yes , it uses `XmlDocument` class with no async implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> even if the method were to return/stop early when if (fbxPath == null)  or if (ShowImportOptions(importOptions))

Not a full answer but to highlight some misunderstanding/potential problem here.

C#'s `Task`'s supports only [cooperative cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads), if `MaterialInfoBank.ReadFromXML` then the [`Task.Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>>, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-8.0#system-threading-tasks-task-run-1(system-func((system-threading-tasks-task((-0))))-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) will only be cancelled if the work has not yet started:

> `cancellationToken` `CancellationToken`
> A cancellation token that can be used to cancel the work if it has not yet started. `Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>>, CancellationToken)` does not pass `cancellationToken` to action.

Which usually should not be the case for you so `MaterialInfoBank.ReadFromXML(filePath)` will almost always run to completion (unless thread pool is very-very busy and have not yet started the task). If you can have resources that require disposal then you need to handle cancellation case correctly. At least something like the following:

```
public static async Task<MaterialInfoBank> BuildMaterialBankAsync(
    StudioViewModel studioView,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken
)
{
    var filePath = $"IncludeResources\\MaterialBanks\\Bank{studioView.TargetedGame}.xml";

    return await Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            var result = MaterialInfoBank.ReadFromXML(filePath);
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                result.Dispose();
            }
            return result;
        },
        cancellationToken
    );
}
```

But better just start the task after `if (fbxPath == null)` check.

As for the potential memory leak - first of all you need to be sure that it is actually a leak (i.e. memory constantly grows and is not fully released when the potentially leaky code is called multiple times). If you have verified that it is a leak (and not some resources which the code initializes and uses through the whole app lifetime) then you will need to analyze what is leaked (by comparing memory snapshots - for example [with dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/How_to_Find_a_Memory_Leak.html#e0b427b8) or via [dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-memory-leak)) and then try to find the code which is allocating those. Without having full minimal reproducible example only we can only guess.

P.S.

Usually there is no need to dispose the `Task` after .NET 4.5 - see [Do I need to dispose of Tasks?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/), so `materialBankTask?.Dispose();` can be removed.

Comment: thank you for reply , i will do as you said also the MaterialBank object is not refrenced or used beyond `ImportFbxAsync` and the method it calls , also i found that calling `ImportFbxAsync` multiple times will not increase the memory usage more than the first time it was called

Comment: @ahmedmoussa _"calling `ImportFbxAsync` multiple times will not increase the memory usage more than the first time it was called "_ - then arguably you don't have a memory leak. Or at least leak which you should worry much about. Can't tell more without having access to the full code.